# Mock not used with @Secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mockito

My mocks are not being picked up when I add a @Secured to any method in the service class and test the service class. This even happens when I am testing a method that isn't secured. I don't understand whether it is due to the mock not being used or being overriden.

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired 
    private DAO dao;

    public void method1() {
       ...
       //System.out.println("DEBUG:" + dao.hashCode());
       dao.XXX();
       ...
    }

    @Secured("...") // added second time (Case 2)
    public void method2() {
        ...
        dao.XXX();
        ...
    }
}

public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private DAO dao;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired 
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testMethod1() {
        Mockito.when(dao.XXX()).thenReturn(...);
        //System.out.println("DEBUG:" + dao.hashCode());
        ...
    }

    public void testMethod2() {
        Mockito.when(dao.XXX()).thenReturn(...);
        ...   
    }
}
```

**Case 1:** 
I test method1 (testMethod1) without the @Secured on method2 and everything works fine. My expected results match what the Mock dao returns.

**Case 2**
I add the @Secured to method2 and re-run testMethod1. The test completes but the results are not matching the Mock dao. The actual dao has been used and the actual results match the database data.

I use the DEBUG statements to print the hashcode of the dao in the ServiceTest class and the Service class. In Case 1 they are the same. In Case 2 they are different.

Apparently there is something happening when I add the @Secured. I want to know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, the difference may be that Spring is creating a Proxy around your Service to handle the `@Secured` annotation, and Mockito cannot handle the injection of the dao in the proxy.

Btw, the same would happen with `@Asynchronous`, `@Transactional` and co.

I would suggest to use the MockitoRunner (forget Spring), or, if you really need to combine Spring and Mockito, use [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations)

Comment: That makes most sense. Do you have any reference to "Spring is creating a Proxy around your Service to handle the @Secured annotation", probably within the documentation?

Comment: @Owl You can have a look at the Spring Docs regarding proxying [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types)

Comment: I just read this as well - http://kim.saabye-pedersen.org/2012/12/mockito-and-spring-proxies.html - just as you mentioned.